# Export sql script with data from postgres database with pgAdmin

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

Hello i want to Export sql script with data from postgres database with pgAdmin but i have a problem and i didn't know where i will get my sql file exported.

Here after i did a backup and format plain and type of objects blobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--file` specification in the command line identifies the name and path to the dump file that is created.

Answer (score 0):

pgAdmin may have started a download in the background. Most modern browsers auto saves the download in the systems Downloads folder, but that all depends on the browser. If you have an icon that shows latest downloaded files you can also look there.

Comment: Hello i'm using microsoft edge but i didn't found anything in the download folder